# MSBuild deploy does not start with TeamCity 10 (but start with TeamCity 8)

Tags: msbuild, teamcity

I have absolutely the same configuration of project and build step at TeamCity 8 and TeamCity 10 (which hosts on different servers).

[image]

Both of them successfully build my project, but after that TeamCity 8 unlike TeamCity 10 start publishing (there is not log information about publishing):

[image]

Have you got any ideas, why is that could happen?

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem you have to copy MSBuild's Web folder with publish targets.

[image]